# What is use of reactJS in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

Friends recently I heard that Magento 2.3 will include react JS with it but I don't know what is the use of it and on what positions it will be used please share some Good resource SO I can understand the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a Progressive Web App Using **React**.

**Progressive Web App (PWA)**

Magento has been forging ahead with the development of PWA Studio -- a suite of tools that allow you to develop, deploy and maintain a PWA storefront on top of Magento 2.

PWA is a new frontend technology that combines the advantages of native apps and websites. PWAs are usually built on a JavaScript framework like **`React`**, **`Vue.js`** or **`AngularJS`** for handling data and displaying it, and communicate with a backend via (Magento 2) REST API.

This approach is also known as **`Headless`** Magento.

Comment: can we use view or angular in place of react?

Comment: @AdarshShukla we can use it.

Comment: I have react.js build and how to integrate it with magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Magento is a highly focused platform which allows users to build a compelling online store. It provides with engaging features that helps in developing the website with absolute satisfaction. For progressive web apps, Magento is going to be a part of Magento 2.3 and will reveal new stacks like React, Jsx, Redux. New front end stacks interduce possible tools and shed light on underlying technologies. The main purpose of React is to build the user interface fast, scalable and simple. It runs in the front-end browser. It helps developers to manage an extensive database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React JS with existing Magento 2 project and theme. You don't need to use PWA Studio or custom build MAgento 2 theme. This module integrates React and webPack with magento js, themes, css, templating  and layout - https://github.com/Genaker/reactmagento2

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the PWA studio documentation to get an overview of the packages and libraries used. It's not Magento, but Magento PWA studio that is built with React: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/guides/project/tools-libraries/.

If you decide to take the route of building a Progressive Web App (PWA), you can consider better alternatives:

- [Vue Storefront](https://www.vuestorefront.io/). Commercial PWA, built with Vue.js - [Demo](https://demo.vuestorefront.io/)
- [GraphCommerce](https://www.graphcommerce.org/). Open Source Magento 2 PWA, built with React - [Demo](https://graphcommerce.vercel.app/)
- [Deity falcon](https://demo.deity.io/). Commercial PWA, built with React - [Demo](https://demo.deity.io/)